# Visual basic -Dados do Listview por tabelas

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim sqlConString As String = "Server=localhost\TESTE;Database=tempTest;User Id=sa;Password=123"
            Try
                Using con = New SqlConnection(sqlConString)
                    con.Open()
                    Using cmd = con.CreateCommand
                '' Para filtrar 
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Clientes where NIF LIKE  '" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from Clientes"
                Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    Dim counter As Int32 = 0
                    While reader.Read
                        ListView1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("NIF")), counter)
                        counter = counter + 1
                        ListView1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Nome")), counter)
                        counter = counter + 1
                        ListView1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Telefone")), counter)
                        counter = counter + 1
                        ''MsgBox(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("NIF")))
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
```

Quero que esteja por cada tabela destas
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UduC3.jpg

Comment: Assim muito dificilmente irá ter ajuda de alguém, edite e coloque o código corretamente e explique melhor a sua dúvida!

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa... esse código não é VB6 (.NET talvez?)

Comment: Isto é VB a minha duvida é em cada um dos ListView1.Item.Add eu quero meter por tabela por exemplo o "NIF" eu quero que esteja na primeira coluna da tabela por baixo do NIF e assim sucivamente

Comment: Já descobri foi assim que fiz

Comment: Dim item As New ListViewItem(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("NIF")))
                            item.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Nome")))
                            item.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Contacto")))
ListView1.Items.Add(item)

Comment: Por que você está carregando a propriedade `CommandText` duas vezes? Dá uma olhada nesse artigo aqui: https://mobile.codeguru.com/vb/controls/vbnet_controls/listview/article.php/c3979/How-to-Fill-a-ListView-with-any-ADONet-Dataset.htm.

Comment: Você precisa usar mesmo o `ListView`? Se você usasse um `DataGridView` ao invés dele, você poderia carregar um DataSet ao invés de um DataReader e joga-lo direto para a propriedade `DataGridView.DataSource`, que ele já criaria as colunas e linhas. É claro que você teria que alterar a sua consulta para retornar apenas as 3 colunas que deseja, e na ordem em que deseja, como: `SELECT NIF, Nome, Telefone FROM Clientes`.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, segue exemplo de como você poderia fazer usando o uma DataGridView.

```
Dim sql = "SELECT IdTipoAlimento, NomeTipoAlimento, NomeAlimento, QtdProteina FROM muscle.tb_alimentos"
Dim dt As Object = DAL.AcessoBD.ExecutarComando(sql, CommandType.Text, Nothing, DAL.AcessoBD.TipoDeComando.ExecuteDataSet)

For intCount As Integer = dt.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
     Me.grdAlimento.Rows.Add(dt.Tables(0).Rows(intCount)("IdTipoAlimento"), dt.Tables(0).Rows(intCount)("NomeAlimento"), dt.Tables(0).Rows(intCount)("NomeTipoAlimento"), dt.Tables(0).Rows(intCount)("QtdProteina"))
     intCount2 = intCount2 + 1
Next
```